# Java.util.Collection.Shuffle not producing random results when using a seeded Random

Tags: java, random, collections

Given the following code:

```
        List<Integer> consensusGroupOrder = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            consensusGroupOrder.add(i + 1);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(consensusGroupOrder, new Random(seed));

        int count = 1;

        Map<Integer, Integer> returnValue = new HashMap<>();

        for(Integer group: consensusGroupOrder) {
            returnValue.put(count++, group);
        }
```

When I set numberOfItems to 4 and starting with a seed of 1, when dumping returnValue as Json I get:

```
{
  "1": 4,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 2,
  "4": 3
}
```

Incrementing seed, the fourth item in the list is always 3. Seed = 5:

```
{
  "1": 4,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 2,
  "4": 3
}
```

Seed = 10:

```
{
  "1": 2,
  "2": 4,
  "3": 1,
  "4": 3
}
```

Seed = 255:

```
{
  "1": 1,
  "2": 2,
  "3": 4,
  "4": 3
}
```

I am seeding Random as I need the result to be deterministic based on seed, but why is the 4th item always 3? Only when seed = 256 does the fourth item change.

I found this question, the answer is to call nextInt() on the Random:  [Collection.shuffle with seeded Random - anomaly with List of size 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002148/collection-shuffle-with-seeded-random-anomaly-with-list-of-size-16)

It feels like calling nextInt() before using the Random is just kicking the problem along the seed value for a while and again it will occur somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java random numbers using a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed)

Comment: @onkarruikar Thanks, but I want the Random to be deterministic dependent on the seed, so not sure that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went with the author proposed work-around on [Collection.shuffle with seeded Random - anomaly with List of size 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002148/collection-shuffle-with-seeded-random-anomaly-with-list-of-size-16):

```
        List<Integer> consensusGroupOrder = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            consensusGroupOrder.add(i + 1);
        }

        Random r = new Random(seed);
        r.nextInt();

        Collections.shuffle(consensusGroupOrder, r);

        int count = 1;

        Map<Integer, Integer> returnValue = new HashMap<>();

        for(Integer group: consensusGroupOrder) {
            returnValue.put(count++, group);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just unlucky! The first positive seed that shuffles a non-3 to the last position is 256. Try this code yourself to find out the first 10 seeds that shuffles a non-3 to the last position.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).filter(Main::lastPositionIsNot3).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static boolean lastPositionIsNot3(long seed) {
    List<Integer> consensusGroupOrder = new ArrayList<>();

    int numberOfItems = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
      consensusGroupOrder.add(i + 1);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(consensusGroupOrder, new Random(seed));

    return consensusGroupOrder.get(3) != 3;
  }
}
```

For the seed 256, the order is 1, 3, 2, 4.

Note that `shuffle` guarantees "All permutations occur with equal likelihood assuming that the source of randomness is fair." Neither `java.util.Random` nor `shuffle` guarantee that there must be a pair of seeds, both of which below 256, that will shuffle lists in such a way that the last elements are different.

If you look at a larger sample size, e.g. all the seeds from 0 to 1 million, and count how many of *those* seeds does not produce 3 as their last element, you will get a more expected result:

```
long count = IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).filter(Main::lastPositionIsNot3).count();
System.out.println(count);
```

This prints 750,404 for me. About 3 quarters of the seeds doesn't shuffle 3 to the end, which is expected. The actual number is 404 seeds (0.05%) more than what we expected. I would expect this percentage to go way lower, if you check the whole range of seeds (0 to 2^48-1) and count how many of those shuffles a non-3 to the end.

In short, The first 256 seeds is too small a sample size to say anything about the distribution of seeds.

Comment: thanks. not sure I fully understand, but suppose I wanted to create an even distribution using a range of say 100 contiguous seeds, would I just multiply the seed by something?

Comment: @SteveFord I think you need to realise just how many seeds there are - 2^48 of them! The first 256 seeds all shuffling a 3 to the last position can hardly be called "uneven". If you want 25 seeds to shuffle a 3 to the end, 25 to shuffle a 2 to the end, 25 to shuffle a 1 to the end, and 25 to shuffle a 4 to the end, then you should find such 100 seeds by trial and error.

Comment: @SteveFord At that point, can you even call it "random" anymore? Why not just hardcode 100 permutations of [1,2,3,4], with exactly the distribution of permutations you want, and select from there? :)